# How add Javascript in GVnix/Spring roo project

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, gvnix

I'm developing a web application and I want add a js file in my project to use it. I tried to add in this way:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/scripts/gestion.js" var="gestion"/>
<script src="${gestion}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The js loads correctly, but the problem is that the page is not showing anything, if I put this code in the end of the jsp file, before of tag `<div>` the jquery and another js file of the project not work although I can see the content of the jsp.

Somebody can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should include it into [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/util/load-scripts.tagx](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/util/load-scripts.tagx) file.

This tag is used by [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx) which is used by [Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) configuration file  [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml) to generate the final html output.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi jmvivo, thanks for your answer. I try do what do you advice me, but It's not working. I added in load-scripts.tagx the following code:   `<!-- Carga de JS adicionales -->
  <spring:url value="/resources/scripts/gestion.js" var="gestion"/>
  <script src="${gestion}" type="text/javascript"></script>`      The JS file is loaded and the jsp file is showing correctly but don't work the code of js file. I tried put this in load-scripts-bootstrap.tagx but I get the same result

Comment: Try to use Devel tools like FireBug to check that there is no error loading nor running JS code. If a JS error is found the JS execution thread is stopped.

Comment: I've used firebug to search some error, but there aren't, or I didn't see it. The js file load is correctly, after of jQuery js file and my js file load fine because I can see the code in firebug. I don't understand why this not working. Anyway I put my js code directly in jsp ...